# Irregularities in Python set comprehensions

Tags: python, for-loop, set, set-comprehension

Why does this set comprehension...

```
>>> {2**x for x in {0,1,2,3,4,5}}
```

Produce this answer?

```
{32, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16}
```

BUT!

This loop...

```
>>> for x in {0,1,2,3,4,5}:
...     print 2**x
```

Produces this answer.

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
```

Comment: `{0,1,2,3,4,5}` happens to be iterated over in ascending order. However, the resulting `set` isn't ordered any more. If you did a list comprehension instead of a set comprehension, you'd see the difference.

Comment: Try `for x in {5,4,3,2,1,0}` too. It's not safe to rely on the order or sets. If you loop over the same set twice without adding/removing elements, you will get the same order, but that's about it.